# Remove duplicates from the list with lists as objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have one list with the class as a structure as below

```
   class cl
    {
        public string name1{ get; set; }
        public string name2{ get; set; }
        public string name3{ get; set; }
        public List<c2> c2List{ get; set; }
    }
   class c2
    {
        public string st1{ get; set; }
        public string str2{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have list of C1 class and i need to remove duplicates from that list
can any one help me how can i do it

Comment: You don't have a `C1` class, nor a `c1` class, it's a `cl` class.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated? what's your criterion? Same name1?

Comment: Why don't you use a Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your after..

```
        var c2Items = new c2[] 
        {
            new c2 { st1 = "value 1", str2 = "value 2" },
            new c2 { st1 = "value 2", str2 = "value 1" },
            new c2 { st1 = "value 1", str2 = "value 2" }
        };

        var parent = new cl() { c2List = new List<c2>(c2Items) };

        IEnumerable<c2> distinctitems = 
            parent
                .c2List
                .GroupBy(o => new { o.st1, o.str2 })
                .Select(o => o.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

When referencing c2List, call it similarly to the below:

```
var distinctList = c1.c2List.Distinct();
```

(Assuming that c1 is instantiated further up the code)